# Socket IO not connecting to the right server.

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, server, sendgrid

I am just starting to learn node and have pieced together little bits and pieces from around the internet. One thing I wanted to use node for was SendGrid to send emails from the client side. I had that working by manually entering `socket = io.connect(http://localhost:8080);`(like everyone says to do) on the socket.io client side. that worked fine locally until i went to host it on heroku or a similar service.

Here is what my **server** code looks like (the functions below don't matter as they are just running sendgrid stuffs:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

// This is the socket.io port. I want the client to go through this.
server.listen(8080);

// this is used to serve a static html page in the public folder.
// I feel like the way I have this set up is part of the issue
app.set('port', (5000));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    console.log('Node app is running on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

I go to the address http://localhost:5000 to view the html for the server.

Here is the **client** code I have written:

```
// Init the socket
socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
// send stuff through it. this stuff doesnt matter. but it sends values
// Via json to the server to then use in an email.
socket.emit('sendCompile', {adr: receptients, bod: body });
```

This gives me the error:

```
socket.io-1.4.5.js:1 GET 
http://localhost/socket.io/?   
EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LFC_cxO
```

Any help would be appreciated. (I have been working on this for over 5 hours :D)

PS: I have already tried changing it to `socket = io();` and `socket = io.connect();` like everyone else seems to think to do. but neither of those work. I feel like it is an issue with how I wrote the server, as I did just piece together things as I found them.

Comment: its possible that in your heroku environment there is already another service listening on 8080 which is causing your emails to not be routed

Answer (score -1):

You need to change the domain from localhost to whatever your website is and add the port, e.g:

```
socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
```

should become

```
socket = io.connect('http://mywebsite.com:8080');
```

Also note that the port you are using for socket needs to be open - you will run into more issues if the port is not open.

Comment: he doesn't need to use mywebsite.com, using localhost will resolve to the box that the site is hosted on hence localhost (this machine).   However your point about opening the port is valid, that should be investigated.

Comment: What if I want to test it with localhost? Is there a way to automate this so I don't have to change it to localhost manually?